# Rails 4 nested resource error created for create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have below routes:

```
resources :venues, shallow: true do
        #Halls
        get "hall/:id/exhibition" => "halls#exhibition", as: :exhibition
        get "hall/:id/visit" => "halls#visit", as: :hall_visit
        get "structure", :to => "venues#venue_structure"
        resources :asset_types, :booths_tags, :tags, :uploaded_files, :events, :chats
        resources :halls do
            resources :webcasts
            resources :booths do
                resources :chats
            end
        end
    end
```

Create action:

```
 # POST /halls
  def create
    @hall = Hall.new(hall_params)

    if @hall.save
      redirect_to @hall, notice: 'Hall was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end 
  end
```

But I'm now getting below error for this:

```
undefined method `halls_path' for #<#<Class:0xb0c7300>:0xab9e7c0>
```

Is there a way to make this `render action: 'new'` part working with redirect back to form validations and error messages?

Rake routes

```
venue_halls_path     GET     /venues/:venue_id/halls(.:format)   halls#index
                     POST    /venues/:venue_id/halls(.:format)   halls#create
new_venue_hall_path  GET     /venues/:venue_id/halls/new(.:format)   halls#new
edit_hall_path       GET     /halls/:id/edit(.:format)   halls#edit
hall_path            GET     /halls/:id(.:format)    halls#show
                     PATCH   /halls/:id(.:format)    halls#update
                     PUT     /halls/:id(.:format)    halls#update
                     DELETE  /halls/:id(.:format)    halls#destroy
```

Comment: Did you try ``rake routes | grep halls`` and see what it came up with?

Comment: I just updated my answer

Comment: you have asked 11 ruby-on-rails questions in the last 7 days - please read the official doc before asking questions

Comment: @emaillenin sorry I did have a look but couldn't find this specific solution also I am coding frequently on rails for the last 7 days that's why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you nest things in Rails like this, when you want to go to that object, you can't just redirect to the object. You have to include the `:venue` as well.

```
@venue = params[:venue] #or however you can get the venue
redirect_to [@venue, @hall], notice: 'Hall was successfully created.'
```

Notice that the path to your object is an array now, because of the way it's nested.

Try that... let me know how it works for you.

Also... read this - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources - read the whole thing, but that's the section on nesting

Comment: thanks a lot. What about `format.html { render action: 'new' }` this part? I'm getting error for this part for `create` action

Comment: That's a different issue, methinks. You're saying too much, too. all you need to say is `render 'halls/new'`. that will render the appropriate view to handle resubmitting the form. The trick to that, is your `halls/new` view is going to be looking for certain `@instanceVariables`. You need to make sure that those variables are available from your create action.

Comment: I tried this `render action: 'venues/#{@venue.id}/events/new'` but this seems to redirect to `venues/#{@venue.id}/events` and missing template error

Comment: read my response again... no `action`. you'll want to redirect to the view that the form is on. if that's from your events controller, then you'll do `render 'events/new'`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I just did `render action: 'events/new'` but I'm getting the same `undefined method `events_path' for #<#<Class:0xcd61d30>:0xcd61220>` error...

Comment: right. you have to make sure all the instance variables that are available to the view when that page is rendered, are available from the create action of the halls controller. (and again, you don't have to say `action:`) - that error will give you more information, and tell you exactly where the issue is. it might deserve a new question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45869/discussion-between-passionate-developer-and-mallanaga)